# On which elections in Germany can I vote?

Tags: germany, elections, eu-citizens

I know that as a EU citizen I am allowed to vote for European Parliamentary candidates. But are there any other elections in Germany on which I can vote too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an EU citizen you are entitled to vote on both the European Parliamentary candidates and on the local/municipal elections. [This is true for all EU countries](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/citizen/voting-rights/index_en.htm), as it's part of the EU citizen voting rights (except if you are not in the country/EU when the election is happening, as in that case you [might not be able to vote](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/328/can-eu-citizens-participate-in-european-parliament-elections-when-living-outside)). You have to forfeit your ability vote in your main countries  EP elections (and possibly also the municipal one, since you are no longer a resident there) though. You still retain the ability to vote on the national elections in your main country, but not in the country you are resident in.

**From the linked site**

EU citizenship gives every EU citizen the right to vote for and stand as a candidate in municipal and European Parliament elections in whichever EU country the citizen resides, under the same conditions as nationals.

There might also be some exceptions:

*Municipal elections*

- an EU country may stipulate that the office of elected head of the executive body of a basic local government unit can only be held by its own nationals
- an EU country may require an additional period of residence for participating in local elections if more than 20% of the eligible voting population are non-nationals.

*European elections*

- You may not vote in more than one EU country in the same European elections
- EU countries may require an additional period of residence for participating in European elections, if more than 20% of the eligible voting population are non-nationals.

Comment: You can vote in municipal elections in both countries (if your country of origin allows it obviously).

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: you usually have to be a resident to vote in the municipal elections, and you usally cannot be (legally) a resident in multiple places. But yes, this is up to the local jurisdictions to decide.

Comment: Your first statement is inaccurate: not every EU country allows its citizens to vote in the EU elections if they live outside the EU. For example, Belgium does not doesn't allow people living outside the EU to vote for the EU elections.

Comment: Well, “usually” maybe but let's be more specific: You can vote in French municipal elections while living abroad if you have a link with a French municipality (including owning land, having lived there in the past or having relatives that live there). You are therefore not forfeiting anything by registering to vote for local elections in another EU country (unlike EU parliament elections, which really work that way EU-wide).

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert The question was about Germany, though.

Comment: Yes, but you're saying "This is true for all EU countries", which implies that your answer is valid for any EU country.

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert I didn't write anything but the answer is in fact valid for all EU countries. EU citizens can vote in Belgium and Belgian citizens can vote in any EU country for municipal and for European Parliament elections, if they reside there. My point was that the question is not about EU citizens living outside the EU.