# Is there any benefit in having two EU nationalities?

Tags: eu-citizens, citizenship, dual-citizenship

Given the single market and many of the EU directives that apply are there any benefits other then patriotism or nationalism that would advocate for having two or more EU citizenships?

Comment: I give it as a comment because **I'm not sure**, but the difference arises when you have **foreign profits** (from without EU) for example from offshore companies. Then you're still oblidged to tax them in your country of citizenship. And the differences between taxes are significant.

Comment: Planning for the day the EU collapses? Also employment in some sensitive positions in the army and elsewhere but you would have to decide if it's a “benefit”.

Comment: This question is obviously pre-Brexit, and not considering the risk of further exits - France, Denmark,  Netherlander, Sweden ... .

Answer (score 22):

Inside the EU, they should have the same benefits, so if you don't plan on leaving the EU, it should not matter.

However countires outside of the EU doesn't look at the EU as a single country, so they can have different (reciprocal) agreements. This includes getting tourist and also work visas outside of the EU. In this case you might get some benefit of having multiple citizenships.

For example if you get a British cizienship you also become a citizen in one of the Commonwealth countries, making it easier to travel to other Commonwealth nations.

An other example is the Visa Waiver Program in the USA, which means that for some countries you don't need to get a visa to travel to the USA for short term. Poland is still not inside this program, but most other EU countries are, so if you only have a Polish Citizenship you cannot benefit from it.

Also note that in some EU countries euroskepticism is becomming prevalent - "Brexit" is already a reality - meaning it might be possible, that an EU country will leave the EU. Although this hasn't happened before(*) so we don't know how the laws will change, but probably this would also mean that if you only have a citizenship in a country that left the EU, you would probably lose the EU citizenship as well.

(*) [Except for Greenland leaving the EEC in 1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenlandic_European_Economic_Community_membership_referendum,_1982) as noted by @gerrit. Note that although Brexit is in progress, we still don't know how it will end, and what will happen afterwards.

Comment: I doubt it, Euroscepticism is the EU equivalent of the skepticism towards the federal government in the US. As such a innocent fact of life.

Comment: But for the rest superb answer

Comment: [Greenland left the EEC in 1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenlandic_European_Economic_Community_membership_referendum,_1982), the UK may be going to have a referendum, and there are many differences between the EU and the USA.  I wouldn't equate the two skepticisms, as they can have very different origins.

Comment: Yea this is completely correct. We have this issue with Polish passports, it has been relaxed recently because less Poles are going to USA now, but a British Naturalised Pole, has better chance to go to USA. Euroscepticism - Too much money to be lost if somebody just decides to pull out.

Comment: @gerrit Greenland as far as I know isn't a country. There are a multitude of territories of member states that are not considered EU.

Comment: @gerrit I would equate both on the base that both skeptical groups are quite ignorant in how the federal and EU bodies influence their life.

Comment: @Andra Almost all in the EU are ignorant of how the EU bodies influence their life, including political representatives on a national level.  The opacity of the EU is in fact one argument against its powers, as it is hinders democracy.  I don't know if the equivalent argument (lack of democracy) is used to argue for US state powers.  If I'm not mistaken, US federal criticism comes mostly from the political right, but EU criticism comes from both left and right.  But let's not turn this into a discussion on the nature of the EU.

Comment: @gerrit I agree to end the dicussion not making it to chatty, but I have heard the ("too much lobbying and not enough democracy") in a US context

Comment: There's a strong seperation attitute in Scotland, and then it can happen that Scots get out of EU by seperating from the rest of UK.

Comment: "Inside the EU, they should have the same benefits, so if you don't plan on leaving the EU, it should not matter." <-- this is not 100% correct.  See the answer by Dirty-flow.

Comment: "For example if you get a British cizienship [sic] you also become a citizen in one of the Commonwealth countries, making it easier to travel to other Commonwealth nations.". This is simply incorrect. I am a British citizen. I am definitely *not* a Canadian citizen, or an Australian citizen.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier it's correct. You have become a citizen of the United Kingdom, which is one of the Commonwealth countries.

Comment: @SztupY I'm sorry, I take it all back. "in one of the". I didn't read it clearly enough. My humble apologies. I don't think this *does* make travel to other countries necessarily easier (there isn't visa-free travel between all Commonwealth pairs), but I jumped on my misunderstanding. Sorry.

Answer (score 12):

To add on to StzupY's answer, a country's nationals often have a much easier time getting things done.
That means, even if the law eventually treats everyone practically the same, foreign EU-nationals usually have to deal with **more paperwork and longer processing times**.

I also think that there are still enough **differences in civil law**, that could have a feelable impact on your life. For example, Polish naming law allows for husband and wife to have two different last-names, taking into account the masculin and feminin suffix. German naming law requires husband and wife to have identical last names.
So for example in Polish, I am Cichocki, and my wife would be Cichocka. If we married under German name-law, my wife would be called Cichocki - which in Polish sounds ridiculous.

I've just started this family-thingy ; ), but I'm prepared to deal with lots of more little nuances, because my wife and I are of different EU-nationalities.

Comment: They other way around is also true. EU citizen sometimes have an easier life then local citizens, simple because for EU citizens the EU law applies as for locals the local law applies. I don't know all details, but once you have lived in another EU country you are legally much more European then if you have stayed in your own country all of your life.

Comment: @Andra this would be new to me, it would be awesome if you posted some examples when you remember any. : )

Comment: The example I know of is about family reunion, which is much easier for EU citizens then it is for locals. I am pretty sure I will pass the details pretty soon, I will then add a link as reference in the comments here

Comment: @Andra That's completely correct and quite relevant but I am guessing that experience was in the Netherlands. You said elsewhere that you were a Dutch citizen but the country is notorious for that, in fact. In other countries, family reunion is typically not easier for EU citizens than for locals.

Comment: The note on German family names isn't quite current any more, but the principle still holds.

Answer (score 10):

As the others have said, the differences are mainly going to be perceptible outside the EU. But even within the union, some countries restrict some of their benefits to actual nationals: for instance, I'm a French citizen living in Sweden, and I can't benefit from their study grant program. I'd have to have the Swedish nationality.

This is the only example I can think of, but I'm sure there are a couple other instances where being an actual national grant you more rights than just being a member state citizen.

Comment: +1, interesting case but I am very surprised and while I am not a lawyer I doubt that this rule would hold if challenged in court (at least if you stayed in Sweden for more than 5 years or if your parents work there; if you just came to study that's a different thing but then the restriction is not strictly speaking based on nationality only).

Comment: Yeah, I shortened it for simplicity, but there are indeed rules where you can get the grant even without having the nationality (as you said, being in the country for 5 years for instance). Still, it's an example of a difference in treatment between EU students and locals, because obviously most foreign students don't fit those criteria.

Answer (score 9):

One advantage could be the work permition - there were some restrictions for citizens of Bulgaria and Romania until 2014, and there are still restrictions for citizens of Croatia - only 8 EU countries don't restrict Croatian workers. So  Croatian citizens (and most likely citizens of upcoming EU members) will benefit from dual EU citizenship

Another point are the elections - you cannot vote on [all elections](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/78/on-which-elections-in-germany-can-i-vote) in the country where you're only resident but not a citizen.

Comment: But the EU citizens *can* vote in *communal* elections in other EU countries, can't they?

Comment: @just-learning yes, EU citizens can vote on communal elections.

Comment: You can also vote in elections to the European Parliament, but you may have to certify that you won't vote in the country of your nationality (you're only eligible to cast one vote in the election, not one per country).

Answer (score 1):

When you have nationality (and citizenship) of one of the European country, you are automatically granted also the European Citizenship.

But the European Citizenship do not make you equal with the Citizens of another EU country.

The rights of a European citizen in european country where he is not citizen can be checked here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship_of_the_European_Union

So the more states you are a citizen the more advantages you get  in those states.

Comment: You can also have disadvantages, where EU law may protect any EU citizens in country X except the nationals of X themselves.